# LLDB summary strings - how to make them persist over Xcode sessions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, debugging, lldb

I am defining lldb summary strings while debugging a program in Xcode 5, for example

```
    type summary add -s "${var._operation} ${var._text}" DMDiff
```

This works fine. However, when I close Xcode, restart it and continue debugging the session, my summary strings are gone. Saving the project beforehand does not make a difference.

My question is: what is the best way to make these summary strings persist from Xcode session to Xcode session, i.e. have them saved in the project or debug information?

Workaround: I did find out that I can define the summary strings in the ~/.lldbinit file in order to make them persist, and this works. Yet it seems kind of cumbersome, and also is global, not on a per-project basis. I might wish a different summary string for a data type in different projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can also give summaries a category, by using the "-w" option to type summary add.  That way you can group related summaries, and turn them all on and off using the "type category {enable/disable}" commands.  If you decide to put your summaries in your .lldbinit, you can then use this trick to switch on the ones that are relevant.

Comment: This is a good trick and works well. Note that if you add your summary format to a category with e.g.
`type summary add -w CNFormatters -s "${var._operation} ${var._text}" DMDiff `
you will not see it listed in the list of summaries:
`type summary list DMDiff` UNTIL you enable the category with:
`type category enable CNFormatters`

In other words, `type summary list` only lists enabled categories, which the inline documentation does not quite tell you.
I still think Xcode should have implemented a mechanism where it keeps such settings automatically from session to session …

Answer (score 1):

You could define these formatters in a file in your project, then make a breakpoint on your app's main(), and associate to it debugger command actions to "command source myFile" and automatically continue

That should do the magic

Comment: That's a good idea too, especially because it keeps the summaries in your own project and thus a little closer than .lldbinit. Thanks!